# Ruby - get method params names and values

Tags: ruby, parameters

Is there a way to get method parameters names and values dynamically, maybe a metaprogramming?

```
def my_method(name, age)
  # some code that solves this issue
end

my_method('John', 22) # => { name: 'John', age: 22 }
```

I want to use this in all my methods in order to log methods calls and respective parameters, but without to do this manually in every method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup! In ruby, it's called the `binding`, which is an object that encapsulates the context in which a particular line runs. The full docs are [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html), but in the case of what you're trying to do...

```
def my_method(arg1, arg2)
  var = arg2
  p binding.local_variables #=> [:arg1, :arg2, :var]
  p binding.local_variable_get(:arg1) #=> 1
  p Hash[binding.local_variables.map{|x| [x, binding.local_variable_get(x)]}] #=> {:arg1 => 1, :arg2 => 2, :var => 2}
end

my_method(1, 2)
```

I'd strongly advise against `Binding#eval`, if you can possibly help it. There's almost always a better way to sovle problems than by using `eval`. Be aware that `binding` encapsulates context on the line at which it is called, so if you were hoping to have a simple `log_parameters_at_this_point` method, you'll either need to pass the binding into that method, or use something cleverer like [`binding_of_caller`](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller)

Comment: Perfect @ymbirtt, many thanks